# Using Azure Cmdlets from a worker role

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, azure, azure-powershell

Is it possible to run the azure powershell cmdlets from a worker role in the cloud?

If so has anyone managed to do it and can provide some kind of explanation on how to get it all setup?

I have this so far, but it won't work.

```
using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
{

    powerShell.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy");
    powerShell.AddParameter("ExecutionPolicy", "RemoteSigned");
    Collection<PSObject> output = powerShell.Invoke();
    ProcessPowerShellOutput(output);

    powerShell.AddCommand("Import-Module");
    powerShell.AddParameter("Name", "Azure");
    output = powerShell.Invoke();
    ProcessPowerShellOutput(output);

    powerShell.AddCommand("Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile");
    powerShell.AddParameter("PublishSettingsFile", @"<PATH>");
    output = powerShell.Invoke();
    ProcessPowerShellOutput(output);

    powerShell.AddCommand("Set-AzureSubscription");
    powerShell.AddParameter("SubscriptionName", @"SUB NAME");
    output = powerShell.Invoke();
    ProcessPowerShellOutput(output);

    powerShell.AddCommand("Set-AzureRole");
    powerShell.AddParameter("ServiceName", @"deploymentconfigtest");
    powerShell.AddParameter("Slot", @"Production");
    powerShell.AddParameter("RoleName", @"DummyWorkerRole");
    powerShell.AddParameter("Count", 2);
    output = powerShell.Invoke();

    ProcessPowerShellOutput(output);

}
```

This is what i run using the powershell console and it runs fine there.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: It's just a computer so I see no reason why not. You probably need to download the Azure Powershell SDK to it first though.

Comment: A worker role is started with a bare VM without Azure Powershell installed. You may need to have a startup task in the worker role configuration to install the Azure Powershell module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by using a C# .NET Libraries,

Nuget Link: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management